# Programmatically setting TextView size makes it smaller than wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am creating a `TextView` element that I size programmatically.  However, the `TextView` is sometimes too small for the text, and sometimes it cuts off additional lines of text.

Is there a way to set a minimum height of a `TextView` to `WRAP_CONTENT`?

**Edit:** The maximum size can be larger than WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: can you please share your whole code, as your text view may depend on its parent container (Layouts)

Comment: More investigation has shown that WRAP_CONTENT would actually create bigger problems, so I figured out a way to hack a minimum size of the TextView as a better workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv= new TextView(context);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: More investigation has shown that WRAP_CONTENT would actually create bigger problems, so I figured out a way to hack a minimum size of the TextView as a better workaround.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code;

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MANAGER LOGIN"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
```

Comment: More investigation has shown that WRAP_CONTENT would actually create bigger problems, so I figured out a way to hack a minimum size of the TextView as a better workaround.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set by programmatically

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: More investigation has shown that WRAP_CONTENT would actually create bigger problems, so I figured out a way to hack a minimum size of the TextView as a better workaround.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
LinearLayout llout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llout);

tv.measure(0, 0);
int text = tv.getMeasuredWidth();
llout.measure(0,0);
int lWidth = llout.getWidth();


if (text > (lWidth / 3)) 
 { 
   tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
 } 
else 
 {
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 }
```

Comment: More investigation has shown that WRAP_CONTENT would actually create bigger problems, so I figured out a way to hack a minimum size of the TextView as a better workaround.  Thank you for your help.